# Read text file, skip some lines, then import values separated by space to SQL Server table

Tags: c#, sql-server, streamreader

I have a text file with 4 Million lines. The structure of the text file is:

```
'DIMENS  '           3 'INTE'
       1000       1000          1
 'MAPUNITS'           1 'CHAR'
 'METRES  ' 
 'GRIDUNIT'           2 'CHAR'
 'METRES  ' 
 'COORDS  '           5 'INTE'
   1 1 1 1 1
 'CORNERS '          24 'REAL'
2665000.000000 -1255000.000000 -468.920181 2665005.000000 -1255000.000000 -469.812128 
2665000.000000 -1255005.000000 -469.004196 2665005.000000 -1255005.000000 -469.896143 
2665000.000000 -1255000.000000 -470.550003 2665005.000000 -1255000.000000 -471.190002 
2665000.000000 -1255005.000000 -470.560001 2665005.000000 -1255005.000000 -471.200000 
 'COORDS  '           5 'INTE'
   2 1 1 2 1
 'CORNERS '          24 'REAL'
2665005.000000 -1255000.000000 -469.812128 2665010.000000 -1255000.000000 -470.704074 
2665005.000000 -1255005.000000 -469.896143 2665010.000000 -1255005.000000 -470.788089 
2665005.000000 -1255000.000000 -471.190002 2665010.000000 -1255000.000000 -471.830002 
2665005.000000 -1255005.000000 -471.200000 2665010.000000 -1255005.000000 -471.839999 
 'COORDS  '           5 'INTE'
   3 1 1 3 1
 'CORNERS '          24 'REAL'
2665010.000000 -1255000.000000 -470.704074 2665015.000000 -1255000.000000 -471.596020 
2665010.000000 -1255005.000000 -470.788089 2665015.000000 -1255005.000000 -471.680035 
2665010.000000 -1255000.000000 -471.830002 2665015.000000 -1255000.000000 -472.470001 
2665010.000000 -1255005.000000 -471.839999 2665015.000000 -1255005.000000 -472.479999 
 'COORDS  '           5 'INTE'
```

What I would like to do is:
1: Read the text file. Is streamreader the right way to go for this?
2: the first 9 lines have to be skipped
3: the space separated values in lines 10 - 13 I want to store in a SQL Server table => 24 Columns, each value in a column
4: then another 3 lines have to be skipped
5: step 3 and 4 are looped until the EOF. But the last line also has to be skipped.

I'm not very good in C#. I could create a streamreader and use the skipline method to skip the first 9 lines but then Icouldn't solve the rest.
Has anybody solved anything similar that I could use as an entry Point?

Best regards
stefan

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary** to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Comment: Might be much easier if you used [File.ReadAllLines()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readalllines(v=vs.110).aspx) and skipped all the streams.